# batch file - getting ip from ping command

Tags: file, redirect, batch-file, ping

i have this command.

```
ping -n 1 piratelufi.com | find /i "reply from"
```

i want to get the ip inside the ping response. i thought of using %var:~0,10% but i have no idea how to redirect the output to echo.

i even tried to use pipe

```
ping -n 1 piratelufi.com | find /i "reply from" | echo %1
```

but the %1 variable does not represent the output of the first two commands. i even tried to use &1 but i failed. What is the 'variable' needed to echo out the output from the first two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `FOR` command it's really cool:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%A IN ('ping -n 1 piratelufi.com') DO IF %%A==Reply ECHO IP IS %%B
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %f in ('ping -4 -n 1 piratelufi.com ^|find /i "pinging"') do echo IP=%f
```