# Scan for valid ip and prints to list

Tags: batch-file, find

```
@echo off
set /a n=0

:repeat
set /a n+=1
echo 192.168.250.%n%
ping -n 1 -w 500 192.168.250.%n% | FIND /i "Reply">>ipaddresses.txt 
if %n% lss 254 goto repeat 

type ipaddresses.txt
```

out put is

```
Reply from 192.168.250.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.250.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 192.168.250.13: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.250.15: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.250.16: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.250.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

So i need a valid ip list. Im taking this code as an example. This is a good coomand in batch, but it outputs the whole reply and i just need the ip, im a noob in batch but im trying to learn. Any ideas on how to remove `Reply from : bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64`? and keep ip

Comment: The key words are `search & replace` or `read a file with batch`

Comment: tags you mean ?  sorry kind of new to this

Comment: Try a look at posts like [getting ip from ping command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171774/batch-file-getting-ip-from-ping-command)

Comment: yeah but every thing i find there is the same problem, it returns the whole reply

Comment: The accepted answer from my link doesn't show the whole thing. Try it with `FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%A IN ('ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 ^| findstr "Reply"') DO ECHO IP IS %%B`

Comment: thanks! but now i have a wierd bug... `@echo off
set /a n=0

:repeat
set /a n+=1
echo 192.168.250.%n%
FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%A IN ('ping -n 1 192.168.250.%n% ^| findstr "Reply"') DO ECHO %%B >>scan.txt
goto :repeat `                           
and the output is the same ip almost every time?! i get 192.168.250.186  90% of the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your workaround you find the [batch beginner bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13741170/463115)

Try this instead

```
@echo off 

(
  FOR /L %%N in (1 1 254) DO (
      echo TEST: 192.168.250.%%N 
      FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%A IN ('ping -n 1 192.168.250.%%N ^| findstr "Reply"') DO ECHO Reply from: %%B
  )
) >scan.txt
```

Comment: i tried it but i still get the bug but with `192.168.250.%n` some times i know that you wrote `192.168.250.%%n` and it should be `192.168.250.%%N` im not 100% sure... Thanks for the feedback !

Comment: I fixed the code, and don't forget that there are two `ECHO`s one to show which IP is tested and one only when it replies

Comment: i dont know what im doing wrong but when i run the code it returns the localhost ip 100% of the time. i dont understand the code as much as i would like to so, dont know how to fix but thanks !

Comment: still get the same error when i run the code i get `192.168.1.1,
192.168.1.10,
192.168.1.10,
192.168.1.10,
192.168.1.10,
192.168.1.10,
192.168.1.8 ,`
it returns the same ip muliple times,

Comment: @TmCookieMonster Then you should copy my example and remove the redirection to the file `>scan.txt` to see what happens